# Blank page in Laravel 4 App

Tags: laravel-4.2

I have a working laravel 4 application and when I upload it on the remote server it's not working and show just blank page for every route
Note: I have install wordpress on root directory of mu server and my app is in subdirectory that I have wordpress on example.com and Laravel app under example.com/subdirectory
May I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.host has been installed php 5.3 and my code needs at least php 5.6.
I called my host provider and asked for installing php 7.1 and after that I found error log in my server and see that I'm correct and solution was right.
Si if you have same issue first check for error log in your server